# How do I select all the values of a table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

$(document).ready(function()
        alert($("td").val());
    });

But the alert is empty.

How do I select the values in my table with jQuery?  Thank you.

edit:  I was asked what for:

I have a website that I need the database data from for a javascript function.  I get the data from the database, put it a table and then select the data from the table for usage in the javascript.  In the middle of my function I hvae the $("td")...whatever form my function.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like them as a comma-separated string of values:

```
var vals = $('td').map(function(){
    return $.text([this]);
}).get().join(',');

alert(vals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Table cells don't have values, they have HTML content.

Use:

```
alert($("td").html().join(','));
```

Instead.

Answer (score 0):

`val` only works on form fields. You want `text`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

alert($("td").text());

});
```

However, text is only goingto retrun one result so youll have to use each to get an array:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var txt = [];
    $("td").each(function(){
       txt[] = $(this).text();
    })
    alert(txt.join(','));

    });
```

Actually, use `map` as J-P suggests... its the better answer for getting the vals in an array :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert($("td").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var values;
$('td').each(function() {
    values += $(this).text() + " ";
});
alert(values);
});
```